# Validation issue

Tags: forms

The first validate function works fine, however the second doesn't. Is there something I'm missing / doing wrong. I want to get the basics of too many characters inputted or too few. Using Drupal 6.

```
function form_example_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  //print('<pre>'.print_r($form_state['values'],1).'</pre>');die(); //THIS LINE WILL   PRINT THE INFO ON A BLANK PAGE FOR TESTING
  if (!is_numeric($form_state['values']['mynumber'])) {
    form_set_error('mynumber',t(' Validation: You must enter a valid number for the number field'));
    return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

$minlength = 5;
if (strlen($form_state['values']['mytextfield']) > $minlength) {
  form_set_error('mytextfield',t(' Validation: The my text field is greater than 5 characters! needs to be smaller'));
  return FALSE;
}
else {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not put in return TRUE, FALSE. form_set_error will make the user come back to the form. The function `return` will return to the previous function which means the rest of your code in `form_example_form_validate` will not be run.

In your example after your first if statement you accidentally close the function with `return TRUE; }`. You have a `}` extra in there. The rest of the code is being run on every load right now (outside a function scope).

Here is a corrected version of you validate function.

```
function form_example_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if (!is_numeric($form_state['values']['mynumber'])){
    form_set_error('mynumber', t(' Validation: You must enter a valid number for the number field.')); 
  }
  $minlength = 5;
  if (strlen($form_state['values']['mytextfield']) > $minlength) {
    form_set_error('mytextfield',t(' Validation: The my text field is greater than 5 characters! needs to be smaller'));
  }
}
```

Comment: One last: do I need to use return false after each one? and then return true after all my validation? or do I just keep adding validation below as in your answer. Thanks again

Comment: Just keep adding if statements with form_set_error inside like the code above. Drupal will mark the form validation as "false" for you so to say.